# Informatica Analyst Rule Logic, Functions and Columns

Tags: informatica

I am using Informatica Analyst and am running a profile on a table data object, along with a rule on this profile. I need help with the syntax in IDQ to do this rule.

For example, in TABLE1  DOB. The column is DOB. I am trying to profile where the DOB is < 18 years old.  The DOB is date time **(mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00).**

This is my attempt:

```
TO_DATE(BIRTHDATE , 'mm/dd/yyyy') > TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM/DD,YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')-18
```

But I'm seeing the following error:

> The expression is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference between sysdate and birthdate should be > 18 years. Pls use this-
DATE_DIFF( SYSDATE, BIRTHDATE, 'Y' ) >18